# Compute QCryptographicHash of only the "core" QImage data (excluding metadata)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qimage

I have a bunch of "JPG" files that are different only for EXIF data.

I wanted to do a quick check (using the Qt Framework), trying to compute the Hash of the "core" image data (and **not** the file itself, which will include the metadata).
So far so good.

*This is how I load an image and compute the Hash:*

```
QImage img(R"(D:\Picture.jpg)");
auto data = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(img.constBits()), int(img.sizeInBytes()));

QCryptographicHash hash(QCryptographicHash::Sha256);
hash.addData(data);
qDebug() << hash.result().toHex();
```

I wanted to extend the same concept to files other than "JPG", so I've saved the original JPG file in different LOSSLESS formats (BMP, PNG, TIF), without altering the resolution.

I got a problem here. The *Hash* of the BMP, PNG, TIF images gives me the same result, but different from that of the same image in JPG.

*If I would create a JPG file from a LOSSLES format I can understand the result.
But the other way round???*

Can someone help me understand where I'm wrong?

*Give the following code I see that:*

- All QImage have the same bytes size
- The QByteArray of the two JPG are identical
- The QByteArray of the BMP, PNG, TIF are identical
- The QByteArray of JPG and BMP (PNG and TIF too) are NOT identical

```
// JPG w/o EXIF data
QImage img1(R"(D:\Picture.jpg)");
auto data1 = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(img1.constBits()), int(img1.sizeInBytes()));

// JPG w/  EXIF data
QImage img2(R"(D:\Picture_EXIF.jpg)");
auto data2 = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(img2.constBits()), int(img2.sizeInBytes()));

// BMP
QImage img3(R"(D:\Picture.bmp)");
auto data3 = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(img3.constBits()), int(img3.sizeInBytes()));

// PNG w/o transparency
QImage img4(R"(D:\Picture.png)");
auto data4 = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(img4.constBits()), int(img4.sizeInBytes()));

// TIF (lossles)
QImage img5(R"(D:\Picture.tif)");
auto data5 = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(img5.constBits()), int(img5.sizeInBytes()));

qDebug() << img1.sizeInBytes(); // 23918592
qDebug() << img2.sizeInBytes(); // 23918592
qDebug() << img3.sizeInBytes(); // 23918592
qDebug() << img4.sizeInBytes(); // 23918592
qDebug() << img5.sizeInBytes(); // 23918592

qDebug() << (data1 == data2); // True
qDebug() << (data1 == data3); // False
qDebug() << (data3 == data4); // True
qDebug() << (data3 == data5); // True

qDebug() << img1.format(); // 4 = QImage::Format_RGB32
qDebug() << img2.format(); // 4 = QImage::Format_RGB32
qDebug() << img3.format(); // 4 = QImage::Format_RGB32
qDebug() << img4.format(); // 5 = QImage::Format_ARGB32
qDebug() << img5.format(); // 6 = QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied

QCryptographicHash hash(QCryptographicHash::Sha256);
hash.reset(); hash.addData(data1); qDebug() << hash.result().toHex(); // c37143639914056add1f90be4bfe780e14500d24f1d3484a087fc1943508157f
hash.reset(); hash.addData(data2); qDebug() << hash.result().toHex(); // c37143639914056add1f90be4bfe780e14500d24f1d3484a087fc1943508157f
hash.reset(); hash.addData(data3); qDebug() << hash.result().toHex(); // 0149c60b883df67ba002d791a1362dbd02ccab09241864341483a16ec0af635d
hash.reset(); hash.addData(data4); qDebug() << hash.result().toHex(); // 0149c60b883df67ba002d791a1362dbd02ccab09241864341483a16ec0af635d
hash.reset(); hash.addData(data5); qDebug() << hash.result().toHex(); // 0149c60b883df67ba002d791a1362dbd02ccab09241864341483a16ec0af635d
```

*Final conclusion*
As in subsequent tests I realized that the problem is neither Qt nor my (last) implementation of the code (thanks @Scheff).
The BMP, PNG and TIF are actually *different* from the original JPG file!

The files BMP, PNG and TIF were created by opening the original JPG file in *Windows Paint* and saving it in those lossless formats. So *Windows Paint* fails somehow in the reading (or) saving steps.
The commercial software *Duplicate Cleaner* fails as well because it reported the JPG file to be 100% identical to the BMP, PNG, TIF version.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202104/discussion-on-question-by-jutta-anders-compute-qcryptographichash-of-only-the-c).

Comment: Try check QPixmap data instead QImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preface:

I consider

```
data1.append(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(img1.constBits()));
```

as wrong way to fill a `QByteArray` with data which doesn't store a C string.

[`QByteArray::append(const char*)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#append-3) is good to copy C strings in a `QByteArray`. It copies data until a 0 byte (a 0-terminator) is found. 0 bytes may be anywhere in the raw data of an image or nowhere. In the first case, too less data is copied, in the latter case, out-of-range data is considered. Both is unintended.

Btw. it's even not necessary to copy the image data (which might be of significant size).

I made a sample to compare the raw data of two `QImage`s directly, including a pre-check whether size and format does match.

My sample `testQImageRawCmp.cc`

```
#include <QtWidgets>

bool equalImgData(const QImage &qImg1, const QImage &qImg2, int eps = 0)
{
  // test properties
#define TEST_PROP(PROP) \
  do if (qImg1.PROP != qImg2.PROP) { \
    qDebug() << "qImg1."#PROP" != qImg2."#PROP; \
    return false; \
  } while(false)
  TEST_PROP(width());
  TEST_PROP(height());
  TEST_PROP(format());
#undef TEST_PROP
  // test raw data
  const uchar *const data1 = qImg1.bits();
  const uchar *const data2 = qImg2.bits();
  const int bytesPerLine1 = qImg1.bytesPerLine();
  const int bytesPerLine2 = qImg2.bytesPerLine();
  const int nBits = qImg1.depth() * qImg1.width();
  const int nBytes = (nBits + 7) / 8;
  assert(nBytes <= bytesPerLine1);
  assert(nBytes <= bytesPerLine2);
  for (int y = 0; y < qImg1.height(); ++y) {
    const uchar *row1 = data1 + y * bytesPerLine1;
    const uchar *row2 = data2 + y * bytesPerLine2;
    for (int x = 0; x < nBytes; ++x) {
      if (abs(row2[x] - row1[x]) > eps) {
        qDebug() << "Row" << y << "byte" << x << "difference:" << (row2[x] - row1[x]);
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  // load sample data
  QImage img1("Picture.jpg");
  QImage img2("Picture.bmp");
#if 0 // U.B.
  // Juttas test:
  QByteArray data1; data1.append(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(img1.constBits()));
  QByteArray data2; data2.append(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(img2.constBits()));
#endif // 0
  // My test:
  if (!equalImgData(img1, img2, 3)) {
    qDebug() << "Images not equal!";
  } else {
    qDebug() << "Images equal.";
  }
}
```

I tested this program with the sample data provided by OP:

- [Picture.jpg](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak5G-Mi8dEN-gq5gS8gSdSx9kvOzbw?e=7SCKqt)
- [Picture.bmp](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak5G-Mi8dEN-gq5hH75lbeVNJRpYIQ?e=NYhQJB)

and got the following output:

```
Qt Version: 5.13.0
Row 0 byte 60 difference: 1
Images not equal!
```

I must admit, the first version of this code just reported the unequality.

Then, I tried to make my own counter-sample and converted the `Picture.bmp` to `Picture.bmp.jpg` in GIMP (with 100 % quality setting which I would've considered as loss-less). This resulted in a difference in `Row 0 byte 0`. Ooops!

Then, I became curious and modified the code to see *how much* different the images are.

A difference of 1 in a red, green, or blue value of a pixel is not much. I doubt that this is even visible for the average human.

Hence, I modified the code (into the exposed version) to tolerate some kind of difference.

With an `eps` of 3:

```
if (equalImgData(img1, img2, 3)) {
```

the images were considered as equal.